# Can an Azure Devops Template declare and define a variable for use later in the same template?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Imagine you have the following trivial Azure Devops template below. My theory is that the template, when used, replaces all the ${{parameters.MyPath}} properly, but the $MyPath exported by setvariable is NOT honored - so on the AzureCLI task, that variable is just empty, since all the replacement happens when the template is inserted.

Is this true? It then seems like the template cannot "pass variables it declares and defines to itself in other parts of the template - like if there was a one time initial variable replacement that cannot happen later on (such as when you declare and define a variable in the first task!). This also seems supported by my inability to add a variables block below parameters to "formalize" the declaration of the variable better.

```
# azure-template.yml

parameters:
    MyPath: 'Path'

 - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Set variable MyPath'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        $MyPath = ${{parameters.MyPath}}
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyPath;]$MyPath"

  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: Print the passed in path
    continueOnError: True
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'Connection'
      scriptType: pscore
      scriptLocation: 'scriptPath'
      arguments: "-FilePath '$(MyPath)'"
      scriptPath: '.pipelines\scripts\PrintOutPath.ps1'
```

I've tried IsOutput=true. I've tried the various [] and $() syntaxes for referring to the declared variable.

Comment: Can you add some more context? This is achievable depending on the details. There are options such as variable templates or writing back the ADO variable to the job scope....however is this a built in runtime variable? Some more background here is needed to provide you with the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are inserted into the template when it is first parsed. As such they can't be changed:

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script)

*Parameters are only available at template parsing time. Parameters are expanded just before the pipeline runs so that values surrounded by ${{ }} are replaced with parameter values. Use variables if you need your values to be more widely available during your pipeline run.*

Answer (score 0):

I think your powershell script is not working, because you're missing the quotes around the value:

```
$MyPath = ${{parameters.MyPath}}
```

When the pipeline is compiled and the parameters are substituted, that becomes:

```
$MyPath = Path
```

And that's not going to do what you want.
Try this instead:

```
$MyPath = '${{parameters.MyPath}}'
```

that will become:

```
$MyPath = 'Path'
```

which will set the powershell variable correctly, and should lead to your pipeline variable being set correctly.